# sort using comparator except for specific value

Tags: java, comparator

I am comparing a list of objects by value. But that value should be my user-defined. I have a list {0,qwerty}{2, abc},{4,xyz},{0,temp}.I Want to sort by first value but I want that all objects having zero at the end. Means I want to sort the values exept zero..how do i do this?

```
Comparator<YourSortableEntity> myCustomComparator =
  new Comparator<YourSortableEntity>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(YourSortableEntity o1, YourSortableEntity o2) {
    int compareVal = o1.getRank() - o2.getRank();
    if (o1.getRank() == 0)
      return compareVal;
    return compareVal;
  }
};
```

Comment: In any case, your if statement has no purpose here, you're just returning the same value that you are returning outside of the if statement.

Comment: `Comparator<YourSortableEntity> myCustomComparator = Comparator.comparing(YourSortableEntity::getRank, Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i == compareVal? Integer.MAX_VALUE: i < compareVal? i: i - 1));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compare(YourSortableEntity o1, YourSortableEntity o2) {
    if(o1.getRank() == o2.getRank()) {
        //futrther logic
    } else if(o1.getRank() == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(o2.getRank() == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else return o1.getRank() - o2.getRank();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    YourSortableEntity e1 = new YourSortableEntity(0);
    YourSortableEntity e2 = new YourSortableEntity(2);
    YourSortableEntity e3 = new YourSortableEntity(4);
    YourSortableEntity e4 = new YourSortableEntity(0);
    YourSortableEntity e5 = new YourSortableEntity(3);
    YourSortableEntity e6 = new YourSortableEntity(0);


    List<YourSortableEntity> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(e1);
    l.add(e2);
    l.add(e3);
    l.add(e4);
    l.add(e5);
    l.add(e6);

    Comparator<YourSortableEntity> myCustomComparator = new Comparator<YourSortableEntity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(YourSortableEntity o1, YourSortableEntity o2) {
            if(o2.getRank()==0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (o1.getRank() == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return o1.getRank() - o2.getRank();
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(l, myCustomComparator);

    for (YourSortableEntity e : l)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getRank());
    }
}
```